# How to split a PDF and keep its form fields

Tags: forms, pdf, pdftk

I am trying to split a multi-paged PDF document that contains form fields (check boxes, text boxes). In case it is important to know, the PDF's form fields are initially all blank/empty/un-checked. I have tried using pdftk and pdfsam, but the form fields in the split pages do not work; they appear, but I am unable to use them.  I can merge multiple PDF documents that contain form fields, and the final product has all the form fields functioning, so it works with merging.

I read the man page for pdftk, searched forums, and have begun reviewing the  [source](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk-2.02-src.zip) (The source seems to be composed of C++ and Java, which are currently beyond my knowledge base), but I have not located an answer to the question: **How can I split a PDF document that contains multiple pages with form fields AND keep the form fields functioning in the split documents?**

I would prefer a solution that uses pdftk, and/or any open-source solution.

Comment: PDFsam version 3.x should retain AcroForms and fields and they should work as expected, were you using version 2.x or 3.x?